# How to reconstruct an image object from a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library, save-image

I have been attempting to break an image (.png) into a list, edit the list, and then save the edited image as a file.

After editing the image, and restoring it into an array, `mpl.imshow(image)` correctly displays the new image, however attempting to save it as a file results in a blank image.

I believe that the flaw lies in the line marked  `# <-- Estimated point of failure`, but I have researched the command and can find no solution to the problem. I have examined the reconstructed array using `print()`, and nothing seems unusual.

Any ideas on how I could correctly save my edited image in file form would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help,
Lochlann F.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl
from PIL import Image

# Desconstruct the image into an editable list
img = Image.open('mini.png')
my_dot_array = np.asarray(img)
my_dot_list = my_dot_array.tolist()
my_dot_list[0][0] = [30, 220, 90, 255] # <-- Attemp a small edit to a pixel in the image

# Reconstuct the image into a saved .png file
my_dot_array = np.asarray(my_dot_list)
img = Image.fromarray(my_dot_array, mode='RGBA') # <-- Estimated point of failure
img = img.save('updated_mini.png')

# Display the resulting image
mpl.imshow(my_dot_array)
mpl.show()


#print(my_dot_array)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are one line out. The line above needs a second parameter `dtype=np.uint8`:

```
my_dot_array = np.asarray(my_dot_list, dtype=np.uint8)
```